# Wildfly 14 + Artemis pooledconnectionfactory jmsXA issue

Tags: wildfly, activemq-artemis

Configured Artemis with ha policy as below:

Machine1: artemis-server1-master

```
<ha-policy>
   <shared-store>
      <master>
         <failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>
      </master>
   </shared-store>
</ha-policy>
```

Machine2: artemis-server2-master

```
<ha-policy>
   <shared-store>
      <master>
         <failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>
      </master>
   </shared-store>
</ha-policy>
```

server1-slave & server2-slave

```
<ha-policy>
   <shared-store>
      <slave>
         <failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>
         <restart-backup>true</restart-backup>
         <allow-failback>true</allow-failback>
      </slave>
   </shared-store>
</ha-policy>
```

In Wildfly, configured Artemis settings below:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:4.0">
    <server name="default">
        <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
        <remote-connector name="remote-artemis1" socket-binding="remote-artemis1"/>
        <remote-connector name="remote-artemis2" socket-binding="remote-artemis2"/>
        <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="remote-artemis1 remote-artemis2" client-failure-check-period="1000" reconnect-attempts="-1" retry-interval="1000" ha="true"/>
        <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="remote-artemis1 remote-artemis2" client-id="Wildfly-14" transaction="xa" user="admin" password="admin" client-failure-check-period="1000" reconnect-attempts="-1" retry-interval="1000" ha="true"/>
    </server>
</subsystem>
```

In ear application, there is a MDB to receiving message. Also using `java:/jmsXA` to lookup connection factory.

After did with above configuration and starts Wildfly, it is successfully processed and send message (i.e. create connection using jmsXA connection factory) to queue. But while processing few files and in between shutdown any of the Artemis master then mdb will receive the message successfully but using `java:/jmsXA` connectionfactory will not able to send message although other master is not down.

Comment: Can you clarify your HA configuration?

Comment: Machine1: artemis-server1-master
<ha-policy>
   <shared-store>
    <master>
     <failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>
    </master>
     </shared-store>
</ha-policy>

Machine2: artemis-server2-master
<ha-policy>
   <shared-store>
    <master>
     <failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>
    </master>
   </shared-store>
  </ha-policy>
server1-slave & server2-slave
<ha-policy><shared-store><slave><failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown><restart-backup>true</restart-backup><allow-failback>true</allow-failback></slave></shared-store></ha-policy>

Comment: I don't really understand the topology. Are the slaves colocated with the live instance or are they dedicated instances? When you shutdown a master do you see the slave take-over (i.e. activate)?

Comment: Yes. When shutdown master, slave become active. Also there is a crisscross matching. Mean backup is master is on another machine. If possible can u plz guide me for correct configuration if above one is wrong